# Nginx Proxy manager cant connect to docker containers

Tags: docker, subdomain, nginx-reverse-proxy, raspberry-pi4

My setup: I have a Raspberry pi at home connected to my Fritzbox 6660 Cable over Lan. The Pi is Running Docker with Portainer. While playing around and learning I was able to deploy numerous different containers with different programs. Now I would like to be able to connect to those containers from outside of my home network. In this example I will describe my Problem with my Grafana Container.(but I tryed other containers as well)
So Currently running are Grafana, InfluxDB(to feed Grafana) and nginx proxy manager.
I setup Nginx with the Docker compose file from nginx`s quick start page:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

once Nginx was running I made sure that Grafana and Nginx are running on the same docker network (nginx_default in this case)

For my custom Domain I signed up for a Duckdns account and created my domain "http://example.duckdns.org"
I used Duckdns`s install instructions to configure the DynDns settings in my fritzbox
with Update-URL:http://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=example&token=xxxxxxx-680f-4c66-a982-60d7e2f56911&ip=
Domainname: example.duckdns.org
username: none (as stated from duckdns install page)
password: xxxxxxxx-680f-4c66-a982-60d7e2f56911
dont worry the "xxxxxx" is actually different in my case.

Further I enabled portforwarding to the static Ip adress of my Raspberry on the ports 80 and 443 since those are the once nginx needs.

Then I went on the nginxpm webpage on port 81 and set up a proxy host like so:
Domain names: grafana.example.duckdns.org (I also tryed without grafana at the beginning, same result)
Scheme: http
Forward Hostname: Raspberry pi Ip
Forward Port: 3000 because thats where I can reach Grafana
I also enabled Block common exploits and websockets support. I know I should enable SSL but wont for this example.

My Nginx now sais this Proxy Host is online. But still I cant connect. Browser says Timeout.
I have this raspberry pi for 2 weeks now and have dumped more than one week just to figure out how to reach over the web. even tryed traefik at some point. But also no success.
I have watched dozens of tutorials, and reconstructed way more than one documentation example. But everytime those tutorials say something about success when they show their container webpage from outside home network. My browsers just give me "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
I also tryed NO_IP and ddnss.
So please if anyone has suggestions I would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious if you could solve this problem because I get a similar error and I tried any possible IP combination in Nginx. I can reach the "Congratulations! You've successfully started the Nginx Proxy Manager." side from outside, but the redirection to the docker container does not work.
Regards